instancing in directx 11
I try to do tiled 2d graphics in direct3d 11. Tiled 2d graphics is basically just a whole lot of textured quads. It seems natural to use instancing to do that, instead of drawing every quad individually. Drawing a single quad works, but if I try to use instancing to draw 2 quads, I get a blank screen.
If I understand it all correctly, the idea is that you create a layout that has the vertex buffer layout in slot 0 and the instance buffer layout in slot 1. You create a vertex buffer with the vertex data and an instance buffer with the instance data. You put those in an array. This is an array of pointers (is that true?). The index in this array corresponds with the slot number in the layout. You receive the vertex data and the index data in the vertex shader and do your thing with it. And then draw it with DrawIndexedInstanced. As usual in directx, understanding it conceptually is the easy bit, making it actually happen is the hard bit.
Here is the code (I know the naming style is not entirely consistent, part is copied from a tutorial).
Definition of the layout:
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputElementDesc[] =
    {
        { "POS", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "TEX", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        {"INSTANCEPOS", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 1, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1},
        {"INSTANCETEX", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 1, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA,1}
    };

    HRESULT hResult = m_device->CreateInputLayout(inputElementDesc, ARRAYSIZE(inputElementDesc), vs_bytecode->GetBufferPointer(), vs_bytecode->GetBufferSize(), &m_layout);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hResult));
    vs_bytecode->Release();```

Binding of the layout:


m_context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
m_context->IASetInputLayout(m_layout.Get());  // m_layout is a ComPtr


Vertex buffer header file:



#pragma once

#include "bindable.h"
#include "base_types.h"

#include <wrl.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>

#include <array>

struct Vertex
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 pos;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 tex_coords;
};

struct Instance_data
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 instance_pos;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 instance_tex;
};


{
public:
class Vertex_buffer : public Bindable
    Vertex_buffer(ID3D11DeviceContext1* context, ID3D11Device1* device, Rect vertex_pos, Rect texture_pos);
    void bind() noexcept override;
    int add_instance(Vec2 pos, Vec2 texture_coords);
private:
    inline constexpr static size_t num_instances{ 2 };
    std::array<Instance_data, num_instances> m_instance_data;
    std::array<ID3D11Buffer*, 2> m_buffers;
    std::array<UINT, 2> m_strides{ sizeof(Vertex), sizeof(Instance_data) };
    std::array<UINT, 2> m_offsets{ 0u, 0u };
    size_t next_index{ 0 };
};    
  



Vertex buffer c++ file


#include "vertex_buffer.h"

#include <array>
#include <vector>

Vertex_buffer::Vertex_buffer(ID3D11DeviceContext1* context, ID3D11Device1* device, Rect vertex_pos, Rect texture_pos) : Bindable{ context, device }
{
    std::array<Vertex, 4> vertices;
    vertices[0]=(Vertex{ DirectX::XMFLOAT2{ vertex_pos.x,  vertex_pos.y }, DirectX::XMFLOAT2{ texture_pos.x, texture_pos.y } });
    vertices[1]=(Vertex{ DirectX::XMFLOAT2 {vertex_pos.x + vertex_pos.width, vertex_pos.y - vertex_pos.height}, DirectX::XMFLOAT2{ texture_pos.x + texture_pos.width, texture_pos.y + texture_pos.height } });
    vertices[2] = (Vertex{ DirectX::XMFLOAT2 { vertex_pos.x, vertex_pos.y - vertex_pos.height }, DirectX::XMFLOAT2{ texture_pos.x, texture_pos.y + texture_pos.height } });
    vertices[3] = (Vertex{ DirectX::XMFLOAT2 {vertex_pos.x + vertex_pos.width,  vertex_pos.y},  DirectX::XMFLOAT2{texture_pos.x + texture_pos.width, texture_pos.y} });

    UINT numVerts = vertices.size();

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc = {};
    vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(vertices);//m_stride * numVerts;//sizeof(vertexData);
    vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexSubresourceData = { vertices.data() };

    //HRESULT hResult = device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexSubresourceData, &m_vertex_buffer);
    HRESULT hResult = device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexSubresourceData, &m_buffers[0]);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hResult));

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC instance_buffer_desc{};
    instance_buffer_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    instance_buffer_desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Instance_data) * num_instances;
    instance_buffer_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    instance_buffer_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    instance_buffer_desc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subres_data{};
    subres_data.pSysMem = m_instance_data.data();
  
    HRESULT hr = device->CreateBuffer(&instance_buffer_desc, &subres_data, &m_buffers[1]);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
}

void Vertex_buffer::bind() noexcept
{
    m_context->IASetVertexBuffers(0u, 2u, m_buffers.data(), m_strides.data(), m_offsets.data());
}

int Vertex_buffer::add_instance(Vec2 pos, Vec2 texture_coords)
{
    m_instance_data[next_index] = Instance_data{ {pos.x, pos.y}, {texture_coords.x, texture_coords.y} };
    return next_index++;
}


shader file


struct VS_Input {
    float2 pos : POS;
    float2 uv : TEX;
    float2 instancepos : INSTANCEPOS;
    float2 instancetex : INSTANCETEX;
};

struct VS_Output {
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD;
};

Texture2D    mytexture : register(t0);
SamplerState mysampler : register(s0);

VS_Output vs_main(VS_Input input)
{
    VS_Output output;
    output.pos = float4(input.instancepos, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    output.uv = input.instancetex;
    return output;
}

float4 ps_main(VS_Output input) : SV_Target
{
    return mytexture.Sample(mysampler, input.uv);   
}


In the main function (there is of course a lot of code that creates the window and does stuff that I know that works)



Vertex_buffer vertex_buffer{ d3d11DeviceContext, d3d11Device, vertex_pos, texture_pos };  // calculated vertex_pos in -1..1 range and texture_pos in 0..1 range
// do the instance data
constexpr unsigned int num_instances{ 2u };
struct Instance_data   // yes, this is defined in 2 places, that should be improved
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 instance_pos;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 instance_tex;
};
std::array<Instance_data, num_instances> instance_data;
Rect v1 = calc_vertex_pos(3.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f, screenwidth, screenheight, 4, 3); // these functions that calculate vertex and texture coordinates work correctly
Rect v2 = calc_vertex_pos(3.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f, screenwidth, screenheight, 3, 2);
Rect t1 = calc_texture_pos(32.0f, 32.0f, 10, 3, 8);
Rect t2 = calc_texture_pos(32.0f, 32.0f, 10, 3, 15);
auto inst0 = vertex_buffer.add_instance({ v1.x, v1.y }, { t1.x, t1.y });
auto inst1 = vertex_buffer.add_instance({ v2.x, v2.y }, { t1.x, t2.y });


in the main loop:



// bind all the things

// ...
layout.bind();
vertex_buffer.bind();
index_buffer.bind();

d3d11DeviceContext->DrawIndexedInstanced(index_buffer.count(), 2u, 0u, 0u, 0u);
d3d11SwapChain->Present(1, 0);


The result is a blank screen. It all compiles and runs, no assertions are hit. I suspect that for some reason the data doesn't get into the shader correctly but I am not aware of any way to debug that.

A few related questions:
1- I assume that binding stuff includes sending the associated data to the graphics hardware. Is it efficient to bind everything every frame (I assume not). Would it work if I only bind things if there are mutations?
2- The instancebuffer description takes the size of the buffer in bytes. Of course it is just a C array underneath. That means that the size is essentially fixed. But the number of objects on the screen can vary: enemies, treasure, bullets and the like can spawn and get destroyed. How do you do that with instancing? Instance only the fixed objects like walls and floors? Or recreate the instance buffer when the number of instances changes? Is recreating the buffer expensive or cheap?
3- Are these semantics names in the shader case-insensitive? I sometimes see SV_POSITION and sometimes SV_Position. Would sv_position also work?

Fiddled around with it quite a bit. Expected two textured quads, got a blank screen.


I see in the debugger that indeed the problem is that the instance data does not get into the vertex shader. In the vertex shader INSTANCEPOS and INSTANCETEX are all zero.

Note you can see an example of using Direct3D 11 instancing in the DirectX Tool Kit for DX11 tutorial here. It is best understood as another way to use 'multi-stream' VBs. The modern docs are a little vague about it because it was a 'new thing' back in Direct3D 9.

@ChuckWalbourn Thanks for the pointer. I wish I found that one earlier. I tried to learn it from the braynzarsoft tutorial. That one does many things at once, which makes it very hard for my limited brain capacity to figure out what is the actual mechanic. IMHO, for a first example, it would be didactically better to stick to a very simple, minimal example, like drawing two trangles or something like that.. And maybe add a more complex example to show what can really be done with it.

OK, got a brainwave and got it working! With the instance buffer.
The trick is that all instances do have access to the vertex buffer data. So, every vertex knows the relative position of the vertex in the vertex buffer. In the instance buffer you store the translation of the entire thing, and that you add to all vertex coords.
So, the recipe is:
for the vertex buffer, define the correct shape, but based in the top left corner of the window (-1, 1).
for every instance, calculate the translation vector (how much do you have to add to the x and y coordinates to get to the new position).
in the shader, do that addition.
For texture coordinates, it is kind of the same: put the coordinates of the top left texture in the vertex buffer (here, to keep things inconsistent, the coordinates go fom (0,0) to (1,1)).
in the instance data put the translation vector.
in the shader add the translation vector to the coords in the vertex buffer.
The shader will now look like this:
struct VS_Input 
{
    float2 pos : POS;
    float2 uv : TEX;
    float2 instancepos : INSTANCEPOS;
    float2 instancetex : INSTANCETEX;
    uint instance_id : SV_InstanceID;
};

struct VS_Output 
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD;
};

VS_Output vs_main(VS_Input input)
{
    VS_Output output;
    output.pos = float4(input.pos.x + input.instancepos.x, input.pos.y - input.instancepos.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    output.uv = float2(input.uv.x + input.instancetex.x, input.uv.y + input.instancetex.y);
    return output;
}


No reactions at all. It seems I am the only person on the internet that tries to do this thing ;-).
I haven't got this working yet, but I do have a couple of observations that might be helpful to others that try to do something like this.

The MSDN documentation is not very good and rather vague. Like when you look up CreateBuffer(), it will say that this function creates the buffer. Yes, I can deduce that from the function name. But what does it actually do? Does it copy the buffer data to the gpu side? It doesn't tell.
It doesn't really tell what D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA does. It turns out that it simply gives the same value for all vertices of the instance. So if you have an instance buffer with two elements, it will give the data of index 0 to all vertices of instance 0 and the data at index 1 to all vertices of instance 1.
I tried to make an instance buffer with D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, hoping that this would give data on a per vertex, per instance basis. Turns out that this doesn't work. CresteBuffer fails with "invalid argument". I haven't done this with all the debug layer stuff active, but it seems it wants only one slot with D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA.
Instancing is supposed to create multiple instances with the same geometry. What exactly does it mean with "the same geometry"? It doesn't tell. I assumed that since the vertex buffer defines relative distances between the corresponding vertex values, instancing would reflect these same relative distances. So, it would create a new triangle of the same size and shape, only at a different position. Turns out it is not that clever. The only things that "the same geometry" does, is that it knows that all instances have the same amount of vertices, the same primitive type (like triangle list) and it uses the same index buffer to make primitives out of the vertices. Nothing more than that. The result is that it just does what's in the vertex shader, with the same data for every vertex. This is fine for a transformation matrix, you want all vertices transformed with the same matrix, but with position data or texture coordinates, it means that it draws all vertices with the same position and the same texture coords, resulting in a blank screen since all vertices are drawn in the same pixel.
It turns out that CreateBuffer snapshots the bufferdata. The shader will see the data like it is the moment CreateBuffer is called. Later changes will  not be reflected at the shader side. There doesn't seem to be a way to mutate the data into the shader side apart from destroying the vertex/instance buffer and re-creating it with different data.
The consequence of all this is, that an instance buffer is really only fitting for data that is the same for all vertices of an instance, and that is rather static. That sounds like a pretty limited usecase to me. Probably they were really thinking of transformation matrices.
So, I got a bit fed up with instance buffers. I think the way to go is a constant buffer. Constant buffers are not really structured, but you can put per vertex, per instance data in there. And constant buffers are (despite the name) not so constant. You can use function Map() to map it to cpu-side memory, make changes and commit those with function Unmap(). Of course MSDN doesn't really tell what happens at Unmap(). Will it copy all data, or just the deltas? It doesn't tell. Given my experiences, I wouldn't gamble on it being superclever and just assume that it copies all the data.
So, I guess I would do something along the lines of creating a constant buffer that contains the positions and texture coordinates of all vertices and all instances, and in the shader do something like:

    #define verts_per_instance 4
    #define num_entities 2
    struct Instance_data
    {
       float2 position;
       float2 texture_coords;
    };
    cbuffer cb
    {
       Instance_data instance[verts_per_instance * num_entities];
    };
    struct VS_in
    {
      uint instance_id : SV_InstanceID;
      uint vertex_id : SV_VertexID;
    };
       
    struct VS_out
    {
       float4 pos : SV_Position;
       float4 tex : TEXCOORD;
    };

    VS_out main(VS_in input)
    {
       VS_out out;
       out.pos = float4(instance[instance_id * verts_per_instance + vertex_id].position.x, instance[instance_id * verts_per_instance + vertex_id].position.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
       // essentially the same for the texture coords;
       return out;
    }

Haven't tried this out yet, but I guess this has the best chance of actually working.
